# winform c# + cefsarp + ExecuteScriptAsync(js) как найти <li">Любитель</li> и программно нажать на эту ссылку

Tags: c#, cefsharp

это текст в браузере

```
<ul class="header_menu" style="vertical-align:top;">
<li class="" onclick="classic();">Классик</li>
<li onclick="sprint();" class="header_menu_hover">Любитель</li>
</ul>
```

этот код я использую для поиска

```
string li =
"var hrefs = document.getElementsByClassName('header_menu');" +
             "var count = 0;" +
             "for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++)" +
             "{" +
                 "if (hrefs[i].textContent.indexOf('Любитель') !== -1)" +
                  "{" +
                     "if (count > 0)" +
                     "{" +
                         "hrefs[i].click();" +
                         "break;" +
                     "}" +
                     "else" +
                     "{" +
                        "count++;" +
                     "}" +
                 "}" +
                "}";

                BotBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(li);
```

и ничего не происходит пробую в консоли тоже не получается

Answer (score 0):

ну на сколько я вижу вы ишите в `классе header_menu` а не в `class="header_menu_hover`
если хотите нажать на почему не добавить ID ?

```
<li onclick="sprint();" id="header_menu_hoverId" class="header_menu_hover">Любитель</li>
```

и выполнить это

```
string li ="document.getElementById('header_menu_hoverId').click();"
```